# Is there any way to clone hardcoded Element or Set of Elements using jquery in runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how to clone hard coded elements in runtime?

I have a hard coded input field. In run time is it possible to read that element and make it multiple(append) by user request. Is that possible with jquery or javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery clone:

```
    <div class="smallBox">
        I'm a small box
        <div class="smallInnerBox">I'm a small small inner box</div>
    </div>

    $('.smallBox').clone().insertAfter(".smallBox");

    <div class="smallBox">
        I'm a small box
        <div class="smallInnerBox">I'm a small small inner box</div>
    </div>
    <div class="smallBox">
        I'm a small box
        <div class="smallInnerBox">I'm a small small inner box</div>
    </div>
```

If you're looking for something a little more comprehensive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id='itemList'>
        <li>
            <input class='input' type="text" value="some text"/>
            <a class='clone' href='Javascript:;'>Clone</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a id='allValues' href='Javascript:;'>Get Values</a>
<script>
    $('a.clone').live('click', function() {
        var clonedItem = $(this).parent().clone();
        clonedItem.find('.input').attr('value', 'cloned');
        $('#itemList').append(clonedItem);
    });

    $('#allValues').click(function(){
        var values = [];
        $('.input').each(function(i, text){
            values[i] = $(text).val();
        });
        alert('Values are: ' + values.join(', '));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it is hard.

Comment: I checked the cloned element. The ID is as same as the parent element. So, there must be a way to get values of the all input fields. What is that!!!???

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "hardcoded"? is this what you need?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#something").click(function(){
        $("#yourform").append($("#yourinputfield"))  
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divElement">Hello</div>
<button onclick="javascript:cloneElement()">Clone Me</button>


function cloneElement()
{
    $("#divElement").clone().appendTo("#divElement");
}
```

Or: http://jsfiddle.net/UFcTk/

Comment: Thanks man, its working. But, it starts to multiply  from 3rd click.

Comment: 1st click, its creating 1, 2nd click its creating 2, 3rd click its creating 4. I will fix it myself. I checked the cloned element. The ID is as same as the parent element. So, there must be a way to get values of the all input fields. What is that!!!???